# Pandas: how to compute the rolling sum of a variable over the last few days but only at a given hour?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'X' : np.random.randn(50000)}, index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=50000, freq='T'))

df.head(10)
Out[37]: 
                            X
2000-01-01 00:00:00 -0.699565
2000-01-01 00:01:00 -0.646129
2000-01-01 00:02:00  1.339314
2000-01-01 00:03:00  0.559563
2000-01-01 00:04:00  1.529063
2000-01-01 00:05:00  0.131740
2000-01-01 00:06:00  1.282263
2000-01-01 00:07:00 -1.003991
2000-01-01 00:08:00 -1.594918
2000-01-01 00:09:00 -0.775230
```

I would like to create a variable that contains the `sum` of X

- over the last 5 days (**not including the current observation**)
- only considering observations that fall at the exact same hour as the current observation.

In other words:

1. At index `2000-01-01 00:00:00`, `df['rolling_sum_same_hour']` contains the sum the values of X observed at `00:00:00` during the last 5 days in the data (not including `2000-01-01` of course).
2. At index  `2000-01-01 00:01:00`, `df['rolling_sum_same_hour']` contains the sum of of X observed at `00:00:01` during the last 5 days and so on.

The intuitive idea is that intraday prices have intraday seasonality, and I want to get rid of it that way.

I tried to use `df['rolling_sum_same_hour']=df.at_time(df.index.minute).rolling(window=5).sum()`

with no success. 
Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: You could try a boolean index: `df['rolling_sum_same_hour'] = df[df.index.hour == 16].rolling(window=10).sum()`. You can make the filter arbitrarily granular to account for minutes, seconds, etc, but it does get verbose...meh

Comment: It's not clear. What values in the `rolling_sum_same_hour` column do you want to have for the rows between hours (for example between: `00:00` and `01:00` - `['00:01', '00:02', ..., '00:59']`)?

Comment: @Noobie: Not to mention the fact that I have no problems with your suggestion!

Comment: hello guys sorry for the ambiguity. The point is the following: FOR EVERY row A in the data, keep observations in the past n days that occurred at the same time as the current observation A.

Comment: i think the question is much clearer now. thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behold the power of `groupby`!

```
df = # as you defined above
df['rolling_sum_by_time'] = df.groupby(df.index.time)['X'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(10).sum())
```

It's a big pill to swallow there, but we are grouping by time (as in python datetime.time), then getting the column we care about (else apply will work on columns - it now works on the time-groups), and then applying the function you want!

Comment: thanks @starfox but I need the rollingsum column to be included in the original dataframe!

Comment: @Noobie: It *should* be as simple as that edit I just made, unless I'm crazy

Comment: thats look pretty good maybe except for the requirement that I should not consider the current observation. Would `x.rolling(10).shift(1).sum()` work to exclude the current obs in the sum?

Comment: To be a little more explicit, if you were to ignore the `shift()`, the rolling sum for 2000-01-01 to 2000-01-10 will appear at that 2000-01-10. Including the `shift()`, the rolling sum for Jan 1-Jan 10 will appear at the index 2000-01-11.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, what you want is to perform a rolling sum, but only on the observations grouped by the exact same time of day. This can be done by

```
df.X.groupby([df.index.hour, df.index.minute]).apply(lambda g: g.rolling(window=5).sum())
```

(Note that your question alternates between 5 and 10 periods.) For example:

```
In [43]: df.X.groupby([df.index.hour, df.index.minute]).apply(lambda g: g.rolling(window=5).sum()).tail()
Out[43]: 
2000-02-04 17:15:00   -2.135887
2000-02-04 17:16:00   -3.056707
2000-02-04 17:17:00    0.813798
2000-02-04 17:18:00   -1.092548
2000-02-04 17:19:00   -0.997104
Freq: T, Name: X, dtype: float64
```